# How to reuse UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have 2 viewcontrollers on my storyboard, which both have a tableview. Now I would like to implement the same cells in both tableviews. Is there a way to easily reuse these cells across multiple viewcontrollers?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this -  "Is there a way to easily reuse these cells across multiple viewcontrollers?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It's possible you need to create .nib file with subclassing UITableviewCell

take a look on https://medium.com/@musawiralishah/creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-nib-xib-files-in-xcode-9bee5824e722#.u8xounci2

you get to know , how to create & use .nib file.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use it by using custom table view cell
[Example for custom table view cell](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should reuse full `UITableView` for this case. There is no open API for sharing cells between multiple `UITableView`s, but you still can reuse `UITableView` in case there is no moment when two controllers are shown simultaneously.